# Dynamic IP Restrictions - Error when installing on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7

I've been trying to install the IIS Dynamic IP Restrictions plugin (http://www.iis.net/download/dynamiciprestrictions) for a while and finally decided to post a question about it.  Whenever I run the installer I get the following error:

---

Product: Dynamic IP Restrictions for IIS 7 - Beta 2 -- Error 1937. An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Management.DynamicIPRestrictions.Client.resources,fileVersion="7.1.891.0",version="1.0.0.000",culture="en",publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35",processorArchitecture="MSIL"'. The signature or catalog could not be verified or is not valid. HRESULT: 0x80131045. assembly interface: IAssemblyCacheItem, function: Commit, component: {6C27138A-C6BE-475C-96B5-1C1FE7878D65}

The signature or catalog could not be verified or is not valid. HRESULT: 0x80131045

---

Any ideas?

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Please try again now. The package has been updated.

Comment: Install return code for product 'Dynamic IP Restriction 1.0 Beta 2' is Failure (An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Management.DynamicIPRestrictions.Client.resources,fileVersion="7.1.891.0",version="1.0.0.000",culture="en",publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35",processorArchitecture="MSIL"'. The signature or catalog could not be verified or is not valid. HRESULT: 0x80131045. )

Comment: any word?  Its pretty sad when the beta doesn't even install.